# What is boto3.client('S3') returning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3

I can see:

```
s = boto3.client('s3')
print(type(s))
```

prints

```
<class 'botocore.client.S3'>
```

But if I try

```
print(botocore.client.S3)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: module 'botocore.client' has no attribute 'S3'
```

How come?

Side note:
My end goal is to return a mock that is speced to what botocore.client.S3 has to offer, but the technical aspect of what is being returned has alluded me for some time, and from knowing that, I'll probably know how to answer my ultimate question.

Answer (score 16):

Through a bit of trial and error, found out the instance type that can be used:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> import botocore
>>> isinstance(boto3.client('s3'), botocore.client.BaseClient)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in @J.Doe's comment, the following lines appear in [`botocore.client.py`](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/a210b26b4d71f752a91247389e735f314f993bf7/botocore/client.py#L179) and are the likely culprits:

```
cls = type(str(class_name), tuple(bases), class_attributes)
return cls
```

What we can see here is that a class is being dynamically created at runtime, rather than being defined in the source code. Many of the other answers do correctly point out that the resulting class is an instance of `BaseClient`, but any of the other dynamically created classes will also be an instance of `BaseClient`, so it's unclear how much use you'll get out of knowing it's a subclass of `BaseClient`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a notion of printing a class object like this (they have no **repr** or **str** methods). If you want to get to the class itself and have a look at all of the methods and parameters, you could do this (using your examples above), if you don't know where botocore and boto3 are installed:

```
>> import boto3
>> import botocore

>> s = boto3.client('s3')

>> print(type(s))
<class 'botocore.client.S3'>

>> print(botcore.client)
<module 'botocore.client' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py'>
```

Now, open the module, '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py', in your favorite editor and see how it works. Additionally, you could have a look at the boto3 and botocore documentation to see how to consume these objects.

- [botocore](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html)
- [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html)

Comment: Even after installing botocore, I still get an exception when I try to do this: 
`isinstance(s, botocore.client.S3)`

Comment: The only way that I've found to verify the boto3 client is to try to use a client method and wrap that in a try/except. From what I remember the "S3" is an enum mapping...

Comment: Yeah, I gave up on trying to do it properly.

Comment: It's `type.__repr__` that produces the observed string; compare `type.__repr__(int)` with `object.__repr__(int)` (which demonstrates that `type` is in fact overriding the `__repr__` method it inherits from `object`).

Answer (score 0):

This module should be helpful.

https://github.com/j4c0bs/boto3-type

In essence...

```
>>> import boto3
>>> import botocore
>>> client = boto3.client('s3')
>>> isinstance(client, botocore.client.BaseClient)
True
>>> client.meta.service_model.service_name
's3'
>>>
```

Specific code from the mentioned [module](https://github.com/j4c0bs/boto3-type) follows.

https://github.com/j4c0bs/boto3-type/blob/db666c4d44666527668016f2f1636c0718a6aef0/boto3_type/common.py#L12-L13

```
def is_client(client):
    return isinstance(client, botocore.client.BaseClient)
```

https://github.com/j4c0bs/boto3-type/blob/db666c4d44666527668016f2f1636c0718a6aef0/boto3_type/client.py#L17-L21

```
    if is_client(client):
    return (
        client.meta.service_model.service_name.lower()
        == service_name.strip().lower()
    )
```