# How do I add type hints to fuctions with boto3 objects in python?

Tags: python, boto3, boto, type-hinting

How do I add type hints to functions using boto3 without using external libraries like mypy_boto3?
This is especially confusing with the boto3.client which returns the object of the type botocore.client.s3 which is unavailable to import.

Example functions to annotate in script below would be `get_client` and `list_objects`:

```
import boto3


def get_client():
    return boto3.client('s3')


def list_objects(client):
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket="a", Prefix="b")
    for content in response.get('Contents', []):
        yield content.get('Key')


client = get_client()
for f in list_objects(client):
    print(f)
```

I am getting started in `typing` module and had a look at different options available in python 3.6+ , but am unclear on what would be the type hints for runtime types like the object returned by `boto3.client` in this case.

Comment: Apparently the runtime type of the object returned by `boto3.client('s3')` is `<class 'botocore.client.S3'>`. Unfortunately adding the corresponding type hint throws: `AttributeError: module 'botocore.client' has no attribute 'S3'`

Answer (score 4):

Per PEP 484 you need to use [Forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) if you're not interested in the external libraries that are being developed.  Just put the type in single quotes.

```
    def get_object(s3_client: 'botocore.client.S3') -> str:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51118767/what-is-boto3-clients3-returning).

That being said, you can do this:

```py
import boto3
import botocore

def get_client():
   client = boto3.client('s3')
   if not (client and isinstance(client, botocore.client.BaseClient):
       do_some_error_handling_here()
   return client


def list_objects(client: botocore.client.BaseClient):
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket="a", Prefix="b")
    for content in response.get('Contents', []):
        yield content.get('Key')


client = get_client()
for f in list_objects(client):
    print(f)
```